# No outline on focused inputs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, web

It seems Firefox no longer displays an outline/highlight on focused elements. When I searched this topic, I got the impression that Firefox did this in the past by default, but discontinued it. Chrome, on the other hand, outlines the selected input with a light blue border:

[image]

I'm trying to create a Greasemonkey script in Firefox that allows users to scroll through checkboxes/radio buttons using the arrow keys. Whichever input is focused should be highlighted so users know it is selected.

Is there anyway to do this in the browser itself, i.e. make it so Firefox highlights the selected elements on pages by default? (Other than downloading a previous version of Firefox or adding CSS to my web site (I need this to work across sites))

I'm using Firefox 40.0.1 and Chrome 55.0.2883.87

Comment: `input:focus{ outline: 1px solid #5b5;}`, wall-off for FF if desired

Comment: Can this be implemented on multiple sites, though? Is there a way to set default styles or something in firefox?

Comment: you can use it wherever you like. it's not bad to make all browsers display your site uniformly to your experience, so long as it's not wildly un-intuitive to users. make it part of your CSS stack and forget about it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant can this be implemented in the browser itself? I'd like focused elements to be outlined on every website I visit. Not just my own

Comment: ahh, for just you. you could use the _stylish_ extension to inject a simple sheet to all sites using a url of `*`, or do the same with a dynamic sheet via grease/tampermonkey. afaik, there's no user-facing setting.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like just what I need.

Comment: Actually, in this case, I'd modify `userChrome.css` rather than use Stylish. (Unless you are unsure of the change and wish to experiment a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `input {outline-style: auto}` in CSS file

Comment: Can you explain to the question poster where to find the relevant CSS file for use with his greasemonkey script?