# Focus ring not showing on page load in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, accessibility

I have a page that sometimes needs focus to be on a particular link when the page loads.  Here is a basic implementation of what I am doing:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.oprah').focus();
});
```

```css
.oprah {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="//www.oprah.com" target="_blank" class="oprah">Oprah!</a>
```

In Chrome this works as expected, with a visible focus ring around the link.  In Firefox, however, the focus ring is not visible.  The link does have focus when checking `document.activeElement` in the console.  Is there something else I need to do to make the focus ring visible in Firefox on page load?

Comment: have you tried to set up the outline with `-moz-` prefix? Look at the [outline browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: JuanCastillo its a border - its not browser specific in this case and borders are working the same across chrome and firefox.
A small suggestion ive seen work in the past @cskowron, try wrapping your $('.oprah').focus(); in a set timeout like so: setTimeout(() => {$('.oprah').focus();},50);
Firefox used to have issues with user permission stealing focus from the user manually and also it used to have issues directly running a focus on load.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried wrapping it in a window.setTimeout and that still gives focus to the link as expected, however the ring that indicates that it has focus is still not showing.

Comment: i did a `<body onload=myfunc()>` where myfunc had `document.getElementById("oprah").focus();` (no jquery) and when the page loaded, the focus was on the link and had the focus border.  (my link had id="oprah").  in your code snippet, when i ran it on firefox, the activeElement was still the "run code snippet" button.

Comment: @cskowron Im not sure which version of FireFox you are running, but to test whether or not its the code or just the browser you could try reverting to an earlier version of FireFox. I saw this which may be of some use; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706797/no-outline-on-focused-inputs-in-firefox

The post suggests FireFox may have discontinued their focus outline, whereas browsers such as Chrome has continued with that. Whether this is true or accurate you may have to investigate further.

Comment: The code works fine for me, on Firefox 62.0 for Linux. I see the curved solid border and the rectangular dotted focus outline. However, I noticed that it didn't work correctly when I tried it in various online snippet editors (StackOverflow, CodePen, JSBin). Are you using one of these? If so, try using the "run in full-page" mode. I also noticed that it worked on JSBin full-page, but only if I was logged out! Example - https://output.jsbin.com/yigutunoci

Comment: Aside: focusing a link on page load sounds like an unusual thing to do. I trust you have a good use-case?